# IPython: Name Error: Name 'x' is not defined

Tags: python-3.x, python-2.7, ipython, ctypes

Using Raspberry Pi 4 and Raspbian OS. I am trying to access BASLER camera from my Python script using below mentioned code.

```
from __future__ import print_function
import sys
from IPython.utils._tokenize_py2 import String
sys.path.append('.')
import numpy, ctypes
Pylonlib = "/opt/pylon5/lib64/libpylonc.so"
from ctypes import cdll
libc = cdll.LoadLibrary(Pylonlib)
libc.PylonInitialize()
#### call any plyon function after you have initialized
libc.PylonTerminate()
```

When I run this code I am getting Name error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "/home/pi/Desktop/cv_ex_1.py", line 3, in <module>
   from IPython.utils._tokenize_py2 import String
   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/IPython/utils/_tokenize_py2.py", line 46, in <module>
       del x
NameError: name 'x' is not defined
```

What can I do to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Consider the code snippet `y = [x for x in [1,2,3]]`. In Python 2, the `x` leaked out of it, so after running it, the global `x` was 3. Python 3 fixed this problem, so running it there results in `x` not being set at the end.

Back when Python 2 was still supported and safe to use, IPython had two different tokenize libraries, one called `_tokenize_py2` and one called `_tokenize_py3`. `_tokenize_py2` contained these two lines:

```
__all__ = [x for x in dir(token) if not x.startswith("_")]
del x
```

The second was intended to address that exact problem. However, you're using Python 3, so `x` already isn't set there, thus causing it to fail. You need to use the Python 3 version of `tokenize` instead. Just switching `_tokenize_py2` to `_tokenize_py3` will accomplish this.